# sweetAlert - not calling function on confirm button click

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I added following alert by following [this](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) but no functions are getting called when I click cancel or confirm buttons, am I doing something wrong? My master page has link to css: `<link href="css/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

```
            sweetAlert({
                html: true,
                title: 'Error',
                text: "test",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Check',            
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    sweetAlert("Yes", "Blah", "info");
                } else {                   
                    sweetAlert("No", "Blah", "info");
                }
                });
```

Comment: Sweet alert also needs its .js file to be included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `jQuery`, attach click event on DOM element where you want to call action, and fire `SweetAlert` popup. Use `SweetAlert` or `sweetAlert` instances to trigger (`fire`) event.

Here is example that will help you start with:

```js
$(function() {
  const events = {
    click: 'click'
  };
  
  const $button = $('#somethingToDo');
  
  $button.on(events.click, function(event) {
    const config = {
      html: true,
      title: 'Error',
      text: 'test',
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Check',    
    };
    
    // first variant
    sweetAlert.fire(config).then(callback);
    
    function callback(result) {
      if (result.value) {
        // second variant 
        SweetAlert.fire("Yes", "Blah", "info");
      } else {
        // second variant 
        SweetAlert.fire("No", "Blah", "info");
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.0.6/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8.0.6/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="somethingToDo">
  Do something
</button>
```